# Jenkins config file provider plugin in a slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use a config file provided by config file provider plugin in a pipeline project.

However when I run a build step inside a slave. I get a "PermissionDenied" exception, The same runs in master however.

So question is thats the best possible way to share files between master and slaves. I may not be able to Copy to slave plugin as there doesn't seem to be pipeline support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share files between stages or nodes you can use the `stash - unstash` methods. see the example [here](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins)

If you want to share files between builds you can use the `archive` method and the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)